# Remotely accessing a device from another on same network without any third party software

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, remote-access, kali-linux

I have a computer and a laptop.Both have internet connection and are on the same network(as laptop is connected via wi-fi and the computer via ethernet).I want to remotely access the computer from my laptop. So the question is that can i do that without any third party software.Or if it is not possible on Windows then can it be done via any another OS like Ubuntu or Kali?

Comment: is MS Remote desktop not sufficient to your needs?

Comment: What Windows version you have? 7,8,10, home, pro....

Comment: I want to secretly control that computer and MS remote desktop asks for the computer name.What if one don't know the name of the computer?

Comment: Well,I am using windows 10 home(not Activated)

Comment: Secretly control someone else's computer? You don't know the computer name? Do you want to make computer people really suspicious? That's how.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer that you want to access has a Professional version of Windows then you can use Remote Desktop.

On the laptop, search for Remote Desktop Connection (or just go to "Run" and type in "mstsc"). Enter the computer name or IP address and hit Connect.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows

Unfortunately, Remote Desktop Or a similar software like Teamviewer is required.

(It is possible to get a linux terminal on windows with the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" (WSL). Let me know if you want more info on this.)

---

### Linux (e.g. Ubuntu)

If you can use a Linux Terminal/Command-line, you can try using SSH. 
The SSH Server may not come pre-installed so you will have to install it.

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

After that, you just need to start the server. The simplest way is to reboot the machine.

To login to the machine you just set up, use an ssh client on another computer, or type this into another Linux terminal:

```
ssh username@IPaddress
```

Obviously replacing the "username" and "IPaddress" with your username on the remote computer and the IP address of the remote computer.

---

### More Info...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH